# Flutter FirestoreListView detect and present widget on no available documents

Tags: flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using [FirestoreListView](https://pub.dev/documentation/app_base/latest/app_base/FirestoreListView-class.html) to fetch documents from Firestore and present them as a list of items (as part of [flutterfire_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_ui) ^0.4.0+5 package).

In case of no available documents (empty QuerySnapshot), the ListView is empty and blank. In that case, I want present a text widget to the screen.

How do I detect and present a widget on empty items using `FirestoreListView`?

Comment: That's what ``empty`` property of FirestoreListView is for!!

Comment: You can pass the widget to the empty parameter which you want to show when the list is empty.

Comment: That property is not available on `flutterfire_ui: ^0.4.0+5`

Comment: Checkout the latest costructor https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/83e2d455d3a083886168b4c115191b06e307a41f/packages/flutterfire_ui/lib/src/firestore/query_builder.dart#L416

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8614

Answer (score 0):

```
FirestoreQueryBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                query: usersQuery,
                builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
                  // Add this part-------------------------
                  if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty) { 
                    return Text('No results found!');
                  }
                  return ListView.builder(
                    //................
                  );
                },
              )
```